# Cannot correctly resize an image at less than 60%

Tags: javascript, html, image

I've implemented a background color modification based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24405245/html5-canvas-change-image-color)

But I want to modify my image size and when I set it below 60%, the image is cropped instead of being resized.

I saw that the problem come from the function `colorImage` but I cannot understand why.

Could you have look [at his fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ndgAlainB/e0nwnhet/10/) and change the width of `img_top` to 50% for example to see the problem?

Comment: I don't know what we're meant to be looking for here? I set it to 50% and it looks alright? http://prnt.sc/b4r379

Comment: @christopher Maybe it could depend on the browser....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You needed to pass the image width/height when using `drawImage`

http://jsfiddle.net/gRoberts/e0nwnhet/11/

```
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.drawImage(imgElement,0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
```

Comment: that's perfect. Thanks a lot.